# accent-color in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I need to change (accent-)color of radio buttons in my application. Thus, I have assigned a new value to `accent-color` property in a global SCSS file:

```
 .checkbox-custom input[type="checkbox"] {
        // ...
        accent-color: $brand-pink;
    }
```

The code compiles and I can see the changes in the browser. But I get this warning in the IDE, which is VS Code:

**Unknown property: 'accent-color'scss(unknownProperties)**

I wonder why I get this warning, though it seems to be a valid property in CSS. Is there any way to get rid of the error?

Comment: if the code is running just fine then you don't need to worry about warning.

Comment: This property is part of the CSS User Interface 4 module, which is only in _draft_ status as of now. Your IDE either simply does not know about it yet, or is set to validate against an earlier standard.